# Lambda casting error

Tags: c#-3.0

I'm using lambda expression and trying convert into uint while adding into the Hashset. Here what I'm doing:

```
HashSet<uint> LeadsInSession = new HashSet<uint>();


if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Category_SelectedLeadIds"] != null)
  {
    Dictionary<LeadPurchase.CategoryLeadSearch, List<string>> toRemoveLeadsIDs =
      (Dictionary<LeadPurchase.CategoryLeadSearch, List<string>>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Category_SelectedLeadIds"];

    LeadPurchase.CategoryLeadSearch searches = (LeadPurchase.CategoryLeadSearch)HttpContext.Current.Session["searches"];

    var toAdd = toRemoveLeadsIDs.Where(Pair => Pair.Key.VerticalID == searches.VerticalID)
                                   .Select(Pair => Pair.Value)
                                   .ToList();

    foreach (var lead in toAdd)
      LeadsInSession.Add(lead);// I need to convert lead into uint. Convert.ToUInt32() didn't work here.

  }
```

Any way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `toRemoveLoasIOs` is a dictionary with a value type of `List<string>`. Therefore `toAdd` will be `IEnumerable<List<string>>`, and thus `lead` is `List<string>` which, quite reasonably will not convert to `uint`.

You need to iterate over both `toAdd` and, an inner loop, over `lead` and then you have the individual `string`s to convert. Something like:

```
foreach (var lead in toAdd) {
  foreach (string value in lead) {
    uint u;
    if (UInt32.TryParse(value, out u)) {
      LeadsInSession.Add(u);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Richard: toRemoveLeadsIDs is dictionary  with a value type of List<string> not List<uint>. And HashSet<uint> accept uint only.

Comment: @user659469: oops, corrected. Underlying issue remains, you need to loop over the inner collection to get to individual strings to convert to numbers.

Comment: @Richard: how do I iterate over toAdd & inner loop? Can u give me an example here?

Comment: Flattening the list first would be better.

Comment: @Jeff in this case I think `SelectMany` would just add to the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Did you Try ?

```
LeadPurchase.CategoryLeadSearch searches
   = (LeadPurchase.CategoryLeadSearch) HttpContext.Current.Session["searches"];
var toAdd = toRemoveLeadsIDs.Where(Pair => Pair.Key.VerticalID == searches.VerticalID)
                            .Select(Pair => (uint)Pair.Value)
                            .ToList<uint>();
foreach (var lead in toAdd)
  LeadsInSession.Add(lead);
}
```

Comment: Yes. I did this. But It won't work as My HashSet<uint> accept only uint & lead is List<string>.

Comment: Maybe as suggested in another answer.. you need to declare hashset as HashSet<List<uint>>